# Replace the <ki> element value into empty <td> element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Replace the `<ki>` element value into empty `<td>` element, If i am using below xsl code my expected output is not coming, Please see current output file

**Input File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kita>
<kk>
    <table id="t001">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p><a href="#MK1">my content here</a></p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><a href="#MK2">my content here</a></p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><a href="#MK3">my content here</a></p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p id="MK1">my content here</p>
    <ki>1</ki>
    <p id="MK2">my content here</p>
    <ki>2</ki>
    <p id="MK3">my content here</p>
    <ki>3</ki>
</kk>
</kita>
```

**Expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kita>
   <kk>
      <table id="t001">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>
                     <a href="#MK1">my content here</a>
                  </p>
               </td>
                <td style="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>
                     <a href="#MK2">my content here</a>
                  </p>
               </td>
                <td style="">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>
                     <a href="#MK3">my content here</a>
                  </p>
               </td>
                <td style="">3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p id="MK1">my content here</p>
      <ki>1</ki>
      <p id="MK2">my content here</p>
      <ki>2</ki>
      <p id="MK3">my content here</p>
      <ki>3</ki>
   </kk>
</kita>
```

**XSL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="td[ancestor::tbody[parent::table/@id = 't001'] and not(normalize-space(.)) and preceding-sibling::td/p/a/@href]">
        <xsl:variable name="tdhref" select="preceding-sibling::td/p/a/substring-after(@href, '#')"/>
        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:value-of select="@style"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::kita/kk/p[@id = $tdhref][1]/following-sibling::ki">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**current output:**
In `<td>` element coming like that below

```
<td><p><a href="#MK1">my content here</a></p></td>
<td style="">123</td>
<td><p><a href="#MK2">my content here</a></p></td>
<td style="">23</td>
<td><p><a href="#MK3">my content here</a></p></td>
<td style="">3</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change `following-sibling::ki` to `following-sibling::ki[1]` - you only want the immediately following sibling, not all of them.